# ActiveRecord Query User Lesson UserLesson

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

**I am trying to display the number of UserLesson.where(user_id: current_user_id) in the provided view (profiles_controller.rb). At the moment it displays the total UserLesson and not to individual user. 
Here is my view:**

```
<% @user.lectures.each do |lecture| %>
        <div class="col-md-4 margin-s mb-60">
          <div class="lecture-box">
            <%= image_tag lecture.picture.url(:medium) %>
            <%= lecture.lessons.size %>

            <%= lecture.lessons.total_lesson %> #SHOULD BE HERE

            <p class="pad5"><%= truncate(lecture.description, length: 80) %> </p>
          <%= link_to "Start Now", lecture, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div> <!-- .lecture-box -->
        </div> <!-- .col-md-4 -->
    <% end %>
```

Here is my lesson.rb:

```
 class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :lecture, through: :chapter
    belongs_to :chapter 
    has_many :user_lessons

    def self.total_lesson
     Lesson.joins(:user_lessons).size
    end 
 end
```

Other Models:

```
 class UserLesson < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user 
belongs_to :lesson
# validates_uniqueness_of :user_lesson, :scope => [:user, :lesson]
end

 class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :lecture, through: :chapter
  belongs_to :chapter 
end

     class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :enrollments
   has_many :user_lessons
   has_many :lectures, through: :enrollments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrollments
 end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user 
belongs_to :lecture
validates :lecture, uniqueness: { scope: :user, message: "should happen once per user" }
 end

class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
has_many :lessons, through: :chapters, dependent: :destroy 
has_many :chapters
belongs_to :teacher

# For course user relationship 
has_many :enrollments 
has_many :users, through: :enrollments

accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrollments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :chapters
```

end

```
 class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lessons
    belongs_to :lecture
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :lessons
 end
```

Comment: It's not clear what you need it to display. Is it the number of lessons that the lecture has in which the current user is (through `UserLesson`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the number of lessons belonging to a lecture in which the current user is related you can do this

```
<%= lecture.lessons.select{ |l| l.users.inculde? current_user }.count %>
```

but you have to add this to `Lesson.rb`:

```
has_many :users, through: :user_lessons
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have `@user` in your view (which is the current_user), so you can just call the following in your view to get the **total number of lessons for this user**:

```
Lesson.joins(:user_lessons).where('user_lessons.user_id = ?', @user.id).count
```

To get the **total number of lessons in this lecture for this user**:

```
Lesson.joins(:user_lessons).joins(:lectures).where('user_lessons.user_id = ? AND lectures.id = ?', @user.id, lecture.id).count
```

where `lecture` is your local variable in your view file.

You should be able to call this directly from your view to get the desired count.